# Im running my first ansible playbook and I get an error even though I followed the video exactly

Tags: ansible, yaml

My first Ansible playbook looks like

```
---
  - name: iluvnano
    hosts: linux

    tasks:

      - name: ensure nano is there
        apt: 
        name: nano
        state: latest
```

I get the error

```
ERROR! conflicting action statements: apt, state

The error appears to be in '/root/test.yml': line 5, column 9, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

tasks:
  - name: ensure nano is there
    ^ here
```

Comment: not enough tabs in the apt and name?

Comment: The answer is given already. Keep in mind that .yml files are sensitive to spaces and tabs as this is the way they get interpreted. I suggest you to use spaces or tabs and set your indentation levels though config files if possible.

Answer (score 1):

According the documentation and examples of [`apt`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html#examples)_module

```
- name: Install apache httpd  (state=present is optional)
  apt:
    name: apache2
    state: present
```

your indents are incorrect. So the error is just caused by a typo and you may use instead

```
  - name: ensure nano is there
    apt: 
      name: nano
      state: latest
```